# What is the difference between "regarding" and "about"?

Tags: vocabulary

How are the words "regarding" and "about" different?

What are the differences in usage, meaning, and grammatical differences?

Is "regarding" more formal than "about"?

I read some iPhone game development book. Following is part of it.

> The iOS Simulator can be used to verify that your code functions, but it cannot measure how well your app performs— questions regarding slow Simulator performance are aplenty on the web. In
>
> Itterheim, Steffen (2014-11-21). Learn SpriteBuilder for iOS Game Development (p. 4). Apress. Kindle Edition.

I think here we can use "about" instead of "regarding".

But almost book used "regarding" include this.

Comment: In general, yes, "regarding" is more formal than "about".  But it would help if you gave a specific sentence where you want to consider using one or the other. There are some cases where one might be preferable, regardless of formality.

Comment: When asking a question like this one, you should also tell us what you already know about the two words. Have you looked them up in a dictionary? If so, what did you find there? (If you leave that information out, there's a good chance that someone will scurry to a dictionary and do that for you, leading to an answer that only tells you what you already know, thereby wasting your time and their time as well). See [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more information and examples on how to improve a question like this one.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, both @BrianHitchcock and @J.R.♦ I added a sentence that where I read it. I usually find "regrading" in books, and "about" in conversation. I am suddenly wandering what they are different.

Comment: In your last sentence, do you mean  "Most books, including this one, use 'regarding'.?  Anyway, I agree with your observation that "regarding" is more common in written English than in spoken English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both terms can mean *having to do with* or *pertaining to the topic/subject of*.

*About* can mean more things, though, such as *all around*.

> He walked about the park looking for John.

You couldn't use *regarding* here.

Also, *regarding* works better at the beginning of sentences, especially if it's the first sentence in a response or conversation.

> Regarding John's performance, I don't think it will improve.
>
> About John's performance, I don't think it will improve.

*Regarding* does have a more "business" feel to it, but there is nothing un-businesslike about *about.*